# Big Sur Safari issues with playback speed

Tags: safari, video, youtube, big-sur

Anyone else having an issue with playback speed changes for video in Safari Big Sur (14.0.1 (16610.3.6.3))?

When I adjust the playback speed the video speeds up, but the audio still plays at normal speed. This happens on YouTube and Skillshare, and probably other sites as well.

I've tried disabling all plugins, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue.

As a workaround, until this bug is fixed, use Firefox for YouTube and Netflix.

Comment: I've never had this issue in Youtube on Safari on macOS Big Sur. Some videos I would play at 1.25x speed and the audio works fine. Although I know that speeding up the videos causes more buffering issues so it will pause and start regularly. It's very choppy sometimes depending on internet connection